# Convergence of series and limit involving partial sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\sum b_n$ converges absolutely.

Is it true that

$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{n=1}^N n^2 b_n = 0?$$

I suspect that this is false but I am finding it difficult to come up with a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true. One way is to use DCT. We have to show that $\sum_n I_{n\leq N} {(\frac n N)^{2} {|b_n|}} \to 0$. Each of the the terms tends to $0$ and the terms are dominated by the terms of $\sum|b_n|$.

Comment: Could you please clarify what $I_{n\leq N}$ means? Thanks.

Comment: @ignoramus it is $1$ if $n \leq N$ and $0$ if $n >N$.